# Directline 3.0 API, StreamUrl with ClientWebSocket

Tags: c#, botframework, direct-line-botframework

I creating a bot connector using Directline 3.0 API. After starting a new Conversation using DirectlineClient object, I get the StreamUrl. How can I use it to communicate with the Bot? I tried one sample given here.(http://itq.nl/net-4-5-websocket-client-without-a-browser/) but it does not work. #botframework

Answer (score 1):

A new sample using C# + DirectLine v3.0 + WebSockets is currently under review and will soon be merged into the [BotBuilder-samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/) repository.

Take a look to this [Pull Request](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/pull/86) to see the code of the new sample.

Comment: I cannot quite the sample. Has it been merged?

Comment: It was but this was a long time ago and so probably it was removed or repurposed. You can still check the PR to see the sample though.